# How to automate Django-App_EXE created by using pyinstaller and innosetup

Tags: python, django, batch-file, inno-setup

I have created an EXE file for my django application. After creating EXE each and everytime i need to run EXE by command line for example :

```
mysite.exe runserver
```

To be more detailed :
OS: windows(CMD), Used pyinstaller to pack all deppendency softwares and later innosetup to make installer.

I have tried to create a batch file to automate the EXE run as given below:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\"Program Files (x86)"\cook_cake\;
start http://localhost:8000 & C:\"Program Files (x86)"\cook_cake\cookie_cake.exe runserver
```

This batch script is not producing desired result.Even this batch script has to run in background when i click on application.
My assumption is error is there in batch script.

Comment: Your provided command line and script don't match, I'm not sure of the purpose of `http://localhost:8000` in your example but if it's a single command, then place it on a separate line; `Start "" "http://localhost:8000"`. Given a commandline of `mysite.exe runserver` and with an executable named `cookie_cake.exe` residing in `\Program Files (x86)\cook_cake\ ` you'd probably use something along the lines of, `Start "" /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\cook_cake" "cookie_cake.exe" runserver`. There should be no need to, _and I wouldn't generally recommend that you_, modify the `%PATH%` variable content.

Comment: `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\cook_cake\;` does not does what you think it does. Hint: spaces and parentheses ...

Comment: @DavidPostill yea, edited that question with "Program Files (x86)"

Comment: @frankhk You still haven't escaped the `(` and `)`

Comment: And `start ... & ...` does not do what you think it does either.

Comment: @DavidPostill i'm new in this. if you can please make clear your valuable answer

Comment: @frankhk, did you not find anything interesting in the first comment or were you so annoyed by something in it that you thought it appropriate to ignore

Comment: @Compo thanks so much its worked fine.

Comment: @Compo The problem is i need to run as administrator otherwise directory accessing is not permitted. How can i do by using batch script. I think setting up a env path can solve this issue as i mentioned in question.

Comment: First of all, neither your question title, body, or comments have mentioned directory access issues, privilege escalation or the words administrator, environment, or `%PATH%`. Secondly you're wrong; appending to or modifying the `%PATH%` variable has got nothing to do with it. Just right click on the batch file and select `Run as administrator` or open `CMD.exe` as administrator and run it from there.

Answer (score 2):

I have alternative solution for that. i am assuming that your **manage.py** file has source similar to code that is mentioned below.

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "WebXapp.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

create one file **PortReader.xml** in your Webapplication folder add this code in it.

```
<Root>
    <Port>8001</Port>
</Root>
```

now, modify your **manage.py**:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "WebXapp.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc

    port = None
    try:
        tree = etree.parse("WebXapp\\PortReader.xml").getroot()
        port = tree.find("Port").text.strip()
    except:
        port = "8000"

    execute_from_command_line(["manage.py","runserver","0:%s"%port])
```

now create executable with pyinstaller. you can use your exe without providing command. also you can modify port from xml file on which your server will run.